# Django: How can you stop long queries from killing your database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, timeout

I'm using Django 1.1 with Mysql 5.* and MyISAM tables.

Some of my queries can take a TON of time for outliers in my data set. These lock the tables and shut the site down. Other times it seems some users cancel the request before it is done and some queries will be stuck in the "Preparing" phase locking all other queries out.

I'm going to try to track down all the corner cases, but its nice to have a safety net so the site doesn't come down.

How do I avoid this? Can I set maximum query times?

Comment: What is an outlier in a data set?

Comment: Someone who has way larger than normal number of achievements, or a really large number of aliases on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't allow you an easy way to avoid this.  A common method is basically to write a script that checks all running processes every X seconds (based on what you think is "long") and kill ones it sees are running too long.  You can at least get some basic diagnostics, however, by setting `log_slow_queries` in MySQL which will write all queries that take longer than 10 seconds into a log.  If that's too long for what you regard as "slow" for your purposes, you can set `long_query_time` to a value other than 10 to change the threshold.

Comment: *sigh* i was afraid of this. Is there any scripts that you recommend for this job?

Comment: did you find any scripts to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a Django DB-replication app and have the same predicament, queries across a WAN can sometimes just seem to hang if the network latency increases.

From http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576780/

Recipe 576780: Timeout for (nearly) any callable

Create a time limited version of any callable.

For example, to limit function `f` to t seconds,
first create a time limited version of `f`.

```
from timelimited import *

f_t = TimeLimited(f, t)
```

Then, instead of invoking `f(...)`, use `f_t` like

```
try:
    r = f_t(...)
except TimeLimitExpired:
    r = ...  # timed out
```

Use it the following way for example:

```
def _run_timed_query(cursor, log_msg, timeout, query_string, *query_args):
    """Run a timed query, do error handling and logging"""
    import sys
    import traceback
    from timelimited import *

    try:
        return TimeLimited(cursor.execute, timeout)(query_string, *query_args)
    except TimeLimitExpired:
        logger_ec.error('%s; Timeout error.' % log_msg)
        raise TimeLimitExpired
    except:
        (exc_type, exc_info, tb) = sys.exc_info()
        logger_ec.error('%s; %s.' % (log_msg, traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_info, None)[0]))
        raise exc_type
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only reliable way to abort a query is the [kill command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html). A less drastic measure is to close the connection (and reopen a new one); this will terminate queries as soon as they try to [send some output](http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/2751) to the client.

Comment: How do I detect this in django? I'd rather not have a cronjob that checks every second to see what it has to kill...

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the queries are? Maybe you could optimise the SQL or put some indexes on your tables?

Comment: Sure, I'm working on the queries. I've found about 4 that kill the DB. But I want a safety net so that there isn't any query that can lock my DB and kill the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use InnoDB Tables, they do [row-locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) instead of [table-locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-locking.html).

Comment: I did that, but I'm mostly reads, and InnoDB was an order of magnitude slowdown for my query load :(

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write queries like that, at least not to run against your live database.  Mysql has a "slow queries" pararameter which you can use to identify the queries that are killing you.   Most of the time, these slow queries are either buggy or can be speeded up by defining a new index or two.